# Need help using member functions as action with Boost Spirit QI

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I'm having trouble getting member functions to bind inside grammar definitions. Compile errors result.

In short:

```
struct my_functor_word
{
  // This code
  void print ( std::string const& s, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type ) const
  // Gives the compiler error seen below. 
  // This code works fine:
  // void operator()( std::string const& s, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type ) const
  {
    std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct bd_parse_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
  template <typename TokenDef> bd_parse_grammar( TokenDef const& tok )
    : bd_parse_grammar::base_type( start )
  {
    my_functor_word mfw;

    start =  *(
      // This code
      tok.word          [boost::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, qi::_1)]
      // gives:
      // {aka void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const}' is not a class, struct, or union type
      //       function_apply;
      //       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ///usr/include/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/detail/function_eval.hpp:126:13: error: 'boost::remove_reference<void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const>::type {aka void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const}' is not a class, struct, or union type
      //             type;
      //             ^~~~

      // This:
      // tok.word          [boost::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, qi::_1)]

      // similarly gives:
      // /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: 'void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const' is not a class, struct, or union type
      // typedef typename F::result_type type;
      
      // This works OK:
      // tok.word          [my_functor_word()] 
      ) ;
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};
```

Here's the whole program. It compiles and functions correctly with functors but not member functions:

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_container.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Lexer>
struct bd_parse_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
  bd_parse_tokens()
  {
    // define patterns (lexer macros) to be used during token definition
    this->self.add_pattern( "WORD", "[a-zA-Z._]+" );

    // define tokens and associate them with the lexer
    word = "{WORD}";    // reference the pattern 'WORD' as defined above

    this->self.add ( word );
  }

  // the token 'word' exposes the matched string as its parser attribute
  lex::token_def<std::string> word;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Grammar definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct my_functor_word
{
  // This code
  void print ( std::string const& s, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type ) const
  // Gives the compiler error seen below. 
  // This code works fine:
  // void operator()( std::string const& s, qi::unused_type, qi::unused_type ) const
  {
    std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct bd_parse_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
  template <typename TokenDef> bd_parse_grammar( TokenDef const& tok )
    : bd_parse_grammar::base_type( start )
  {
    my_functor_word mfw;

    start =  *(
      // This code
      tok.word          [boost::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, qi::_1)]
      // gives:
      // {aka void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const}' is not a class, struct, or union type
      //       function_apply;
      //       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ///usr/include/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/detail/function_eval.hpp:126:13: error: 'boost::remove_reference<void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const>::type {aka void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const}' is not a class, struct, or union type
      //             type;
      //             ^~~~

      // This:
      // tok.word          [boost::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, qi::_1)]

      // similarly gives:
      // /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: 'void (my_functor_word::*)(const std::basic_string<char>&, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::unused_type) const' is not a class, struct, or union type
      // typedef typename F::result_type type;
      
      // This works OK:
      // tok.word          [my_functor_word()] 
      ) ;
  }
  qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  //  Define the token type to be used: `std::string` is available as the
  //   type of the token attribute
  typedef lex::lexertl::token < char const*, boost::mpl::vector<std::string> > token_type;

  //  Define the lexer type to use implementing the state machine
  typedef lex::lexertl::lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

  //  Define the iterator type exposed by the lexer type */
  typedef bd_parse_tokens<lexer_type>::iterator_type iterator_type;

  // now we use the types defined above to create the lexer and grammar
  // object instances needed to invoke the parsing process
  bd_parse_tokens<lexer_type> bd_parse;          // Our lexer
  bd_parse_grammar<iterator_type> g( bd_parse ); // Our parser

  // read in the file int memory
  std::string str( argv[1] );
  char const* first = str.c_str();
  char const* last = &first[str.size()];

  bool r = lex::tokenize_and_parse( first, last, bd_parse, g );

  if ( ! r )
  {
    std::string rest( first, last );
    std::cerr << "Parsing failed\n" << "stopped at: \""
          << rest << "\"\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many aspects to this puzzle.

Firstly, to bind a member function you have to pass the extra leading instance parameter (the `this` object).

Secondly, semantic actions are Phoenix Actors, so deferred functors. `boost::bind` are likely not what you wantL you **cannot** call `my_functor_word::print` with `qi::_1_type` anyways. Instead you might use `phoenix::bind`, in which case you don't even have to deal with the "magic" context parameters:

```
struct my_functor_word {
    void print(std::string const& s) const {
        std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And

```
start = *(tok.word[ //
    boost::phoenix::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, qi::_1)]);
```

### That Was It?

I won't let you go without some more observations.

Firstly, the bind is still broken! You bound `mfw` as the `this` instance, but `mfw` is a local variable. The nature of the semantic action (being a *defferred actor* as said above)  is that it will be called *during parse*: **long after the constructor is finished**. The `mfw` needs to be a member variable. Or better, not be a part of the grammar at all. I'd suggest

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Grammar definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Iterator>
struct bd_parse_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    bd_parse_grammar(TokenDef const& tok) : bd_parse_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        start = *tok.word[px::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, _1)];
    }

  private:
    struct my_functor_word {
        void print(std::string const& s)
        {
            std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl;
        }
    };

    mutable my_functor_word mfw;
    qi::rule<Iterator>      start;
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I see a lot of old-fashioned and questionable style. E.g. why are you including `boost/bind.hpp` (or even `boost/bind/bind.hpp`) and even `boost/lambda.hpp`?

Why are you using Lex?

You're using `using namespace` liberally, which is a bad idea, *especially* when mixing all these libraries (that literally **all** have their own idea of placeholders named *1 etc*). Instead just make some aliases:

```
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace px  = boost::phoenix;
```

You have a comment

```
// read in the file int memory
```

That doesn't match the code given:

```
std::string str(argv[1]);
char const* first = str.c_str();
char const* last  = &first[str.size()];
```

That is just weird all around. Why are you using raw `char*` with a string (it has proper iterators with `begin()` and `end()`?). Also, maybe you really wanted to read a file?

By the way, let's make sure `argv[1]` is actually **valid**:

```
for (std::string fname : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);

    // read in the file into memory
    std::string const str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    auto first = str.begin(), //
        last   = str.end();
```

So here's a demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdaecaa0c2043916)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace px  = boost::phoenix;

template <typename Lexer> struct bd_parse_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer> {
    bd_parse_tokens() {
        this->self.add_pattern("WORD", "[a-zA-Z._]+");
        word = "{WORD}";
        this->self.add(word);
    }

    // the token 'word' exposes the matched string as its parser attribute
    lex::token_def<std::string> word;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Grammar definition
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Iterator>
struct bd_parse_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    bd_parse_grammar(TokenDef const& tok) : bd_parse_grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        start = *tok.word[px::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, _1)];
    }

  private:
    struct my_functor_word {
        void print(std::string const& s) const { std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl; }
    };

    mutable my_functor_word mfw;
    qi::rule<Iterator>      start;
};
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // type of the token attribute
    using token_type    = lex::lexertl::token<std::string::const_iterator,
                                           boost::mpl::vector<std::string>>;
    using lexer_type    = lex::lexertl::/*actor_*/lexer<token_type>;
    using iterator_type = bd_parse_tokens<lexer_type>::iterator_type;

    bd_parse_tokens<lexer_type>     bd_parse;
    bd_parse_grammar<iterator_type> g(bd_parse);

    for (std::string fname : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        std::ifstream ifs(fname);

        // read in the file into memory
        std::string const str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

        auto first = str.begin();
        auto last  = str.end();

        bool ok = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, last, bd_parse, g);

        std::cerr << "Parsing " << fname << " (length " << str.length() << ") "
                  << (ok ? "succeeded" : "failed") << "\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cerr << "Stopped at #" << std::distance(str.begin(), first)
                      << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
word:includeboostspiritincludelex_lexertl.hppincludeboostspiritincludephoenix.hppincludeboostspiritincludeqi.hppincludefstreamincludeiomanipnamespaceqiboostspiritqinamespacelexboostspiritlexnamespacepxboostphoenixtemplatetypenameLexerstructbd_parse_tokenslexlexerLexerbd_parse_tokensthisself.add_patternWORDazAZ._wordWORDthisself.addwordthetokenwordexposesthematchedstringasitsparserattributelextoken_defstdstringwordGrammardefinitiontemplatetypenameIteratorstructbd_parse_grammarqigrammarIteratortemplatetypenameTokenDefbd_parse_grammarTokenDefconsttokbd_parse_grammarbase_typestartusingnamespaceqilabelsstarttok.wordpxbindmy_functor_wordprintmfw_privatestructmy_functor_wordvoidprintstdstringconstsconststdcoutwordsstdendlmutablemy_functor_wordmfwqiruleIteratorstartintmainintargccharargvtypeofthetokenattributeusingtoken_typelexlexertltokenstdstringconst_iteratorboostmplvectorstdstringusinglexer_typelexlexertlactor_lexertoken_typeusingiterator_typebd_parse_tokenslexer_typeiterator_typebd_parse_tokenslexer_typebd_parsebd_parse_grammariterator_typegbd_parseforstdstringfnamestdvectorargvargvargcstdifstreamifsfnamereadinthefileintomemorystdstringconststrstdistreambuf_iteratorcharifsautofirststr.beginautolaststr.endbooloklextokenize_and_parsefirstlastbd_parsegstdcerrParsingfnamelengthstr.lengthoksucceededfailedniffirstlaststdcerrStoppedatstddistancestr.beginfirstn
Parsing input.txt (length 1367) succeeded
Parsing main.cpp (length 2479) succeeded
Stopped at #0
```

### Without Lex

I think this would be strictly simpler:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7da12fcf1c360f75)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px  = boost::phoenix;

template <typename Iterator>
struct bd_parse_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
    bd_parse_grammar() : bd_parse_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi::labels;
        word  = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z_.");
        start = *word[px::bind(&my_functor_word::print, &mfw, _1)];
    }

  private:
    struct my_functor_word {
        void print(std::string const& s) const { std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl; }
    };

    mutable my_functor_word mfw;
    qi::rule<Iterator>                start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> word;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bd_parse_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> const g;

    for (std::string fname : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        std::ifstream ifs(fname);

        // read the file into memory
        std::string const str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

        auto first = str.begin();
        auto last  = str.end();

        bool ok = qi::parse(first, last, g);

        std::cerr << "Parsing " << fname << " (length " << str.length() << ") "
                  << (ok ? "succeeded" : "failed") << "\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cerr << "Stopped at #" << std::distance(str.begin(), first)
                      << "\n";
    }
}
```

Same output

### Without Phoenix Bind

Using some C++17 CTAD and phoenix::function:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/638740959b6cd521)**

```
template <typename Iterator> struct Parser : qi::grammar<Iterator> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        px::function print{[](std::string const& s) {
            std::cout << "word:" << s << std::endl;
        }};

        word  = +qi::char_("a-zA-Z_.");
        start = *word[print(qi::_1)];
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator>                start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> word;
};
```

Only half the original code.

### Using X3

If you're using C++14 anyways, consider slashing compile times:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5483ebe5132e3aed)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Parser {
    auto print = [](auto& ctx) {
        std::cout << "word:" << _attr(ctx) << std::endl;
    };
    auto word  = +x3::char_("a-zA-Z_.");
    auto start = *word[print];
} // namespace Parser

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (std::string fname : std::vector(argv + 1, argv + argc)) {
        std::ifstream ifs(fname);

        // read the file into memory
        std::string const str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

        auto first = str.begin();
        auto last  = str.end();

        bool ok = x3::parse(first, last, Parser::start);

        std::cerr << "Parsing " << fname << " (length " << str.length() << ") "
                  << (ok ? "succeeded" : "failed") << "\n";

        if (first != last)
            std::cerr << "Stopped at #" << std::distance(str.begin(), first) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Still the same output.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks, @sehe for the quick and comprehensive response. I posted a cut down example based on www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/actions.cpp which passed a class (w) to the parse() function and didn't have the lifetime problem my code has. Thank you for pointing that out. That example also had lots of includes and using statements which I left in... I'm using lex because there are numerous other token types that I left out to make my example simpler. LIkewise with the string stuff. That was just a hack for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Just a general word of advice: Lex is not used by the authors of the library, and doesn't exist anymore in the new X3 versions of Spirit